# Can't run initial karma.conf.js that I get from "karma init" because of "require not defined" despite not using it

Tags: macos, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I ran a simple `karma init` and pressed enter throughout the process to get the following karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Jan 21 2016 10:32:15 GMT-0600 (CST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        '**/*.spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

However, after trying to run a simple test that looks like:

```
describe('test', function() {
    it('should return true', function() {
        expect(true).toEqual('true');
    })
});
```

While it runs, I get the following output:

```
1 01 2016 10:32:47.879:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
21 01 2016 10:32:47.888:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.19 server started at http://localhost:9876/
21 01 2016 10:32:47.892:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
21 01 2016 10:32:50.192:INFO [Chrome 47.0.2526 (Mac OS X 10.11.3)]: Connected on socket /#RpTiNDwYyXuP29hTAAAA with id 21512010
Chrome 47.0.2526 (Mac OS X 10.11.3) ERROR
  Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
  at /Users/sgarcia/dev/karma/hello-karma/node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher/test/jsflags.spec.js:1
```

Why does it say it can't find requireJS despite me not using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your list of files:

```
files: [
    '**/*.spec.js'
],
```

That will catch ALL your *.spec.js files, which is why it found "/Users/sgarcia/dev/karma/hello-karma/node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher/test/jsflags.spec.js" which is a test for the developers of karma-chrome-launcher itself, which does indeed have a call to requireJS, and which you probably don't want to include in your test suite :-)

Consider place all your test files in **./test** and changing you karma.conf.js files section to something like:

```
files: [
    'js/**/*.js',
    'tests/**/*.spec.js'
],
```